# Performant parsing of HTML pages with Node.js and XPath

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xpath, phantomjs

I'm into some web scraping with Node.js. I'd like to use XPath as I can generate it semi-automatically with several sorts of GUI. The problem is that I cannot find a way to do this effectively.

1. `jsdom` is extremely slow. It's parsing 500KiB file in a minute or so with full CPU load and a heavy memory footprint.
2. Popular libraries for HTML parsing (e.g. `cheerio`) neither support XPath, nor expose W3C-compliant DOM.
3. Effective HTML parsing is, obviously, implemented in WebKit, so using `phantom` or `casper` would be an option, but those require to be running in a special way, not just `node <script>`. I cannot rely on the risk implied by this change. For example, it's much more difficult to find how to run `node-inspector` with `phantom`.
4. `Spooky` is an option, but it's [buggy enough](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/71), so that it didn't run at all on my machine.

What's the right way to parse an HTML page with XPath then?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath or https://github.com/yaronn/xpath.js?

Comment: @mb21 Any performant DOM implementation to run them?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do so in several steps.

1. Parse HTML with `parse5`. The bad part is that the result is not DOM. Though it's fast enough and W3C-compiant.
2. Serialize it to XHTML with `xmlserializer` that accepts DOM-like structures of `parse5` as input.
3. Parse that XHTML again with `xmldom`. Now you finally have that DOM.
4. The `xpath` library builds upon `xmldom`, allowing you to run XPath queries. Be aware that XHTML has its own namespace, and queries like `//a` won't work.

Finally you get something like this.

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const xpath = require('xpath');
const parse5 = require('parse5');
const xmlser = require('xmlserializer');
const dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

(async () => {
    const html = await fs.readFile('./test.htm');
    const document = parse5.parse(html.toString());
    const xhtml = xmlser.serializeToString(document);
    const doc = new dom().parseFromString(xhtml);
    const select = xpath.useNamespaces({"x": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});
    const nodes = select("//x:a/@href", doc);
    console.log(nodes);
})();
```

Note that you have to prepend every single HTML element of a query with the `x:` prefix, for example to match an `a` inside a `div` you would need:

```
//x:div/x:a
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Except that I needed to replace `var document = parser.parse(html.toString());` by `var document = parse5.parse(html.toString());` and get rid of the line `var parser = new parse5.Parser();` (using parse5 version 2.0.2)

Comment: You are loading everything in memory (the entire DOM)... is there a more memory efficient way to do this?

Comment: I wondering if it is possible to create a custom parse5 treeAdapter that would avoid the serializeToString/parseFromString step ?  (see https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/blob/master/packages/parse5/docs/options/parser-options.md#optional-treeadapter)

Comment: @Fabiosoft Unfortunately XPath queries do require DOM. There were implementations of subset of XPath that worked over a SAX parser for PHP, but (I almost hope that) there is no such thing on npm.

Comment: @FranckFreiburger If I were to do any web crawlers today, I'd just use CSS selectors. They lack features like walking back to some parent, but you won't need anything beyond a call to `parse5`. XML and tooling around it (like XPath or Java) fell out of mainstream some time back in 2014.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to not have to add `x:` before every single element.

Answer (score 16):

[Libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) is currently the fastest implementation (something [like a benchmark](https://github.com/blue-button/bluebutton.js/issues/97)) since it's only bindings to the [LibXML](http://xmlsoft.org/) C-library which supports XPath 1.0 queries:

```
var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml);
// xpath queries
var gchild = xmlDoc.get('//grandchild');
```

However, you need to sanitize your HTML first and convert it to proper XML. For that you could either use the [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) command line utility (`tidy -q -asxml input.html`), or if you want it to keep node-only, something like [xmlserializer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmlserializer) should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have just started using [`npm install htmlstrip-native`](https://github.com/zaro/node-htmlstrip-native) which uses a [native implementation](https://github.com/zaro/node-htmlstrip-native/blob/master/htmlstrip.cpp) to parse and extract the relevant html parts.  It is claiming to be 50 times faster than the pure js implementation (I have not verified that claim).

Depending on your needs you can use html-strip directly, or lift the code and bindings to make you own C++ used internally in htmlstrip-native

If you want to use xpath, then use the wrapper already avaialble here;
   https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath

Comment: 0. Your link is broken. 1. That library is parsing entities, and that's quite obvious from its name. 2. XPath is not even mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Fixed the broken link; added link to the xpath implementation, any reason you didn't find/use that yourself?

Comment: That `xpath` library has to be run over some kind of DOM. The only solution that parses HTML is `jsdom`, which is slow as hell. It's the first item in the list up there. Did you read the question?

Comment: If you were to read the `npm xpath` documentation you would see that he suggest using the xmldom .

Comment: And how xmldom is supposed to parse HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I think [Osmosis](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis) is what you're looking for.

> - Uses native libxml C bindings
> - Supports CSS 3.0 and XPath 1.0 selector hybrids
> - Sizzle selectors, Slick selectors, and more
> - No large dependencies like jQuery, cheerio, or jsdom
> - HTML parser features
>
>   - Fast parsing
>   - Very fast searching
>   - Small memory footprint
> - HTML DOM features
>
>   - Load and search ajax content
>   - DOM interaction and events
>   - Execute embedded and remote scripts
>   - Execute code in the DOM

[Here's an example:](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis/blob/9c23441187950febc3e605b843a1295064c13550/test/find.js#L71)

```
osmosis.get(url)
    .find('//div[@class]/ul[2]/li')
    .then(function () {
        count++;
    })
    .done(function () {
        assert.ok(count == 2);
        assert.done();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

With just one line, you can do it with [`xpath-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath-html):

```js
const xpath = require("xpath-html");

const node = xpath.fromPageSource(html).findElement("//*[text()='Made with love by']");
```

Comment: It's good that you've made a library that incapsulates an answer by @pda. If a better approach shows up, it's possible to update only one library. On the other hand it's a little bit shady that you don't mention this is your library, and that this library is basically another answer from this thread.

Comment: Worth noting that this has one/some serious bugs right now: https://github.com/hieuvp/xpath-html/issues/10#issuecomment-752248148