# Extract data from html source file with specified template

Tags: html, node.js, templates, extract

I want to parse the value from a source file by a specified template.

Let say, I have this:

**Template:**

```
<div>{value}</div>
<span id="id1">{value}</span>
<div><span>{value}</span></div>
```

**Source file:**

```
<h1>The source file can have other parts but will contain the specified template structure</h1>
<div>value 1</div>
<span id="id1">value 2</span>
<div>or a bit more complex content...<span>value 3</span><a>abc</a></div>
<h2>other file content again</h2>
```

The expected output is an array: [**value 1, value 2, value 3**]

Anyone know a NodeJS module for this purpose ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no lib for this purpose.
I have my own solution by thinking another way, so the question should be: how can I parse the web content.
And the answer is: we can use the xpath as what discussed here: [Performant parsing of pages with Node.js and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753368/performant-parsing-of-pages-with-node-js-and-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hext-library for this: https://github.com/html-extract/hext